# Divisibility between values of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810001052) Corvaja and Zannier considered the following problem. Let $K$ be a number field, and let $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing the infinite places and let $\mathcal{O}_S$ be its ring of $S$-integers. One may enlarge $S$ so that $\mathcal{O}_S$ is a PID. Suppose that $f_i, g_i$ are polynomials in $\mathcal{O}_S[x,y]$ for $i = 1,2,3$. Then they showed (see Theorem 2) that under certain genericness assumptions that the set of points $(x,y) \in \mathcal{O}_S^2$ satisfying

$$\displaystyle f_i(x,y) | g_i(x,y), i = 1,2,3$$

is not Zariski dense. Moreover, they showed that none of the assumptions they made can be dropped. In particular, there are easy counter-examples when $i = 1,2$.

In my situation, I wish to consider a variant of this problem in the case $i = 2$. Take single variable polynomials $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and a polynomial $q(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. What can we say about the number of integral points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ with $\max\{|x|, |y|\} \leq T$ such that

$$\displaystyle q(x,y) | \gcd(f(x), g(y))?$$

Can any aspect of Corjava-Zannier be applied in this setting, and if not, are there any other methods to count such points?